# Lmfit minimization with 2 independent variables provides inappropriate result

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, least-squares, minimize, lmfit

I am trying to use limit with 2 independent (x1,x2) variables.  As an equation employed modified [Bass model](http://www.bassbasement.org/BassModel/Default.aspx). The result of minimization func do not represent correct estimation of 'q' parameter (negative value), therefore, chart depicted improperly. Presumably, I executed something worn, could you help to solve?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Parameters, fit_report, minimize

#Define Data & Variables
x1=np.array(df['cumulative__sales'])
x2=np.array(df['cumulative_sales_2'])
y_p=df['sales']

t1=np.linspace(1,55,(len(yp)))

def b_func(params,x1,x2,yp):   
    p = params['p']
    m = params['m']
    q = params['q']
    b = params['b']
    model= (p*m)+(q-p)*x1+(-q/m)*x1**2+(x2*b)*(m-x1)
    return model - yp

# Define Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('m', value=1003)
params.add('p', value=0.03, min=0.0001)
params.add('q', value=0.05,  min=0.001)
params.add('b', value=-0.05)

# For non-linear leastsq algorithm
minner = Minimizer(b_func, params, fcn_args=(x1,x2,yp))
result = minner.minimize()
```

The report illustrates that 'q' parameter is negative (estimated wrong). if I add boundary min= 0.001, then parameter is not calculated at all, and equal to initial value.

```
# Final result
final = yp + result.residual
report_fit(result)



           m:  1281.66188  (3.58%) (init = 1003)
           p:  0.01251625  (9.86%) (init = 0.03)
Negative - > q: -0.47443242  (37.85%) (init = 0.05)
           b:  3.3332e-04  (36.21%) (init = -0.05)
```

But according to Bass rule it could not be possible, for means there is no buyers. Thus, chart depicted improperly Y-value, it ought to placed by S-shape(goes tangentially). With negative P value:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJeHm.png)

Representative equation and graph without additional variable x2 only x1 and Y :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OH6m.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/573yz.png)

Modified version of equation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuXB6.png)

The chart with min bound q=0.01, but parameter is not calculated and always equal the initial value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeJck.png)

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Sorry, but `p` looks positive to me.  Please include a complete example and the complete output.

Comment: Dear professor, I added supplementary information and graphs. Plausibly the issue with modified equation.

Comment: um, `p` is positive and larger than the lower limit you set.  `q` is negative, but you didn't place any bounds on `q`.

Comment: Thanks for your notice, I added bound for q, but in this case, q-parameter not calculated at all and each time merely equals the initial value. The aim of modified equation is add second independent variable (x2) whose values almost correspond to x1 (first indep.variable) and increase precision of dependent variable Y.

Comment: um (for the third and final time), no. If you say that `q` has a minimum value of 0.001, the fit will NOT return a negative value for `q`, as your question now states.  And what you report does not have `q` at its initial value. In the future, you will want to ask a full and complete question and include the full, unedited output that you actually got, with any (full, unedited) error messages.